# Towards a square filling curve and Lindenmayer system drawing library

Tags: graphics, recursion, fractals, lindenmayer

[image: The first two iterations and elementary modifications]

I am trying to obtain the first terms of a sequence of curves that converges to a curve in the family of well known [plane (or space) filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve). This is a variation I found in the book "Topology" by James Munkres (see the figure above).

Fig. 44.1 and Fig. 44.2 describe the first two curves (images of functions *g* and *g'* respectively) and, at the same time, the operation for going from one step to the next.  For example, the next curve will be obtained by applying this same operation to each of the four parts (lying in the four small squares) of *g'*.  The operation respects the geometrical orientation of each part; see Fig. 44.3.

I have tried using pgf and tikz to draw them but not being too familiar with Lindenmayer systems, I am having a hard time obtaining them. Following is the code I have tried so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{curve 1} {
    \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \symbol{+}{\pgflsystemturnright}
    \symbol{-}{\pgflsystemturnleft}
    \rule{A -> -AXB--XA++XB++XA--XB++XA++XB--XA}
    \rule{B -> +BXA++XB--XA--XB++XA--XB--XA++XB}
}

\foreach \x in {1,2,3} {
\tikz\draw[lindenmayer system={curve 1, axiom=A, order=\x, angle=45}, scale=1.5] lindenmayer system;
\vskip .5in
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: The first two terms]

To define the orientation along the curve, the **left** side of it is colored.  In the image above we see the first two terms of the sequence *u*.  In passing from one term to the next, elementary operations are performed on each portion of the current curve (called *elementary part* in the sequel).  There are four types of elementary parts, *up*, *right*, *down*, and *left*.  They are replaced at each step.  For example, *right* yields the curve below.

[image: right]

The next step for each elementary part:

[image: next step]

The first four terms of the sequence.

[image: first four terms]

I don't know how to use a Lindenmayer system.  So the code is based on the construction of four `pic` elements, one for each elementary part.  These elements are defined recursively, each taking two arguments: the recursion step and the recursion bound.
There is also a constant `\r` that **must be defined** at the beginning; it controls the scaling factor.

**Remark.** The curves of the sequence are not simple (they auto intersect, i.e. the corresponding function is not injective.  The code can be slightly modified (see the Hilbert curve) to obtain simple curves.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % for show control points
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  pics/up/.style 2 args={% recursion step, end
    code={%
      \tikzmath{
        integer \i;
        \i = #1+1;
        \tmp = {\r/pow(2, \i)};
        if \i<#2 then {%
          {%
            \path (-\tmp, -\tmp) pic {right={\i}{#2}};
            \path (-\tmp, \tmp) pic {up={\i}{#2}};
            \path (\tmp, \tmp) pic {up={\i}{#2}};
            \path (\tmp, -\tmp) pic {left={\i}{#2}};
          };
        } else {%
          {%
            \fill[opacity=.2] (-2*\tmp, -2*\tmp) -- (0, 0)
            -- (2*\tmp, -2*\tmp) -- ++(0, 4*\tmp) -| cycle;
            \draw (-2*\tmp, -2*\tmp) -- (0, 0) -- (2*\tmp, -2*\tmp);
          };
        };
      }
    }
  },
  pics/right/.style 2 args={% recursion step, end
    code={%
      \tikzmath{
        integer \i;
        \i = #1+1;
        \tmp = {\r/pow(2, \i)};
        if \i<#2 then {%
          {%
            \path (-\tmp, -\tmp) pic {up={\i}{#2}};
            \path (\tmp, -\tmp) pic {right={\i}{#2}};
            \path (\tmp, \tmp) pic {right={\i}{#2}};
            \path (-\tmp, \tmp) pic {down={\i}{#2}};
          };
        } else {%
          {%
            \fill[opacity=.2] (-2*\tmp, -2*\tmp)
            -- (0, 0) -- (-2*\tmp, 2*\tmp) -- cycle;
            \draw (-2*\tmp, -2*\tmp) -- (0, 0) -- (-2*\tmp, 2*\tmp);
          };
        };
      }
    }
  },
  pics/down/.style 2 args={% recursion step, end
    code={%
      \tikzmath{
        integer \i;
        \i = #1+1;
        \tmp = {\r/pow(2, \i)};
        if \i<#2 then {%
          {%
            \path (\tmp, \tmp) pic {left={\i}{#2}};
            \path (\tmp, -\tmp) pic {down={\i}{#2}};
            \path (-\tmp, -\tmp) pic {down={\i}{#2}};
            \path (-\tmp, \tmp) pic {right={\i}{#2}};
          };
        } else {%
          {%
            \fill[opacity=.2] (2*\tmp, 2*\tmp) -- (0, 0)
            -- (-2*\tmp, 2*\tmp) -- ++(0, -4*\tmp) -| cycle;
            \draw (2*\tmp, 2*\tmp) -- (0, 0) -- (-2*\tmp, 2*\tmp);
          };
        };
      }
    }
  },  
  pics/left/.style 2 args={% recursion step, end
    code={%
      \tikzmath{
        integer \i;
        \i = #1+1;
        \tmp = {\r/pow(2, \i)};
        if \i<#2 then {%
          {%
            \path (\tmp, \tmp) pic {down={\i}{#2}};
            \path (-\tmp, \tmp) pic {left={\i}{#2}};
            \path (-\tmp, -\tmp) pic {left={\i}{#2}};
            \path (\tmp, -\tmp) pic {up={\i}{#2}};
          };
        } else {%
          {%
            \fill[opacity=.2] (2*\tmp, 2*\tmp) -- (0, 0)
            -- (2*\tmp, -2*\tmp) -- cycle;
            \draw (2*\tmp, 2*\tmp) -- (0, 0) -- (2*\tmp, -2*\tmp);
          };
        };
      }
    }
  },
  pics/context1/.style 2 args={% color, function's name
    code={%
      \draw[thin, ->] (-.5*\r, 0) -- ++(2.5*\r, 0);
      \draw[#1, very thick] (0, 0) -- ++(1.5*\r, 0);
      \foreach \i in {0, .5, 1}{
        \draw[thick, #1] (\i*1.5*\r, 0) -- +(0, 1ex);
      }
      \foreach \i in {0, 1}{
        \draw[thick, #1] (\i*1.5*\r, 0) -- +(0, -1ex) 
         node[below, scale=.7] {$\i$};
      }
      
      \draw[->] (2.5*\r, .5*\r) to[out=20, in=160] ++(\r, 0);
      \path (2.5*\r, 0) +(.5*\r, .75*\r) node[scale=.7] {$#2_1$}; 
    }
  },
  pics/context2/.style 2 args={% color, function's name
    code={%
      \draw[thin, ->] (-.5*\r, 0) -- ++(2.5*\r, 0);
      \draw[#1, very thick] (0, 0) -- ++(1.5*\r, 0);
      \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using {1.5*\r/8*\i}] in {0, ..., 8}{
        \draw[thick, #1] (\k, 0) -- +(0, 1ex);
      }
      \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using {1.5*\r/4*\i}] in {0, ..., 4}{
        \draw[thick, #1] (\k, 0) -- +(0, -1ex);
      }
      \foreach \i in {0, 1}{
        \path[#1] (\i*1.5*\r, 0) -- +(0, -1ex) node[below, scale=.7] {$\i$};
      }
      
      \draw[->] (2.5*\r, .5*\r) to[out=20, in=160] ++(\r, 0);
      \path (2.5*\r, 0) +(.5*\r, .75*\r) node[scale=.7] {$#2_2$};
    }
  }
}

% \begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={\r=1.2;}]
%   \path (-5*\r, -.5*\r) pic {context1={red}{u}};  % u_1
%   \draw[gray, thin] (-\r, -\r) rectangle (\r, \r);
%   \path (0, 0) pic[red, thick, fill=gray] {up={0}{1}};

%   \begin{scope}[yshift={-2.5*\r cm}]  % u_2
%     \path (-5*\r, -.5*\r) pic {context2={red}{u}};    
%     \draw[gray, thin] (-\r, -\r) rectangle (\r, \r);
%     \draw[gray, thin] (-\r, 0) -- (\r, 0);
%     \draw[gray, thin] (0, -\r) -- (0, \r);
%     \path (0, 0) pic[red, thick, fill=gray] {up={0}{2}};
%   \end{scope}
% \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={\r=1.7;}]
  \foreach \s in {1, ..., 4}{%
    \begin{scope}[xshift={(\s-1)*2.3*\r cm}]
      \draw[gray, thin] (-\r, -\r) rectangle (\r, \r);
      \path (0, 0) pic[red, thick, fill=gray] {up={0}{\s}};
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are waiting for some help with a Lindenmayer system, here is a different approach using [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

We start with a right-angle path `gene` centered at the origin.  Then
in the loop make a 1/2 scale copy of the path (`gg`) and then replace
`gene` with four copies of `gg` appropriately rotated and shifted.  The length of the path quadruples each time, so after the fifth loop (shown above) it is 2048 points long.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibnumbersystem{double}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path gene; gene = (dir 225 -- origin -- dir 315) scaled 256;
    for i = 1 upto 5:
        path gg; gg = gene scaled 1/2; numeric n; n = length gg;
        gene := reverse gg rotated -90 shifted  point 0 of gg &
                        gg             shifted -point n of gg &
                        gg             shifted -point 0 of gg &
                reverse gg rotated +90 shifted  point n of gg;
    endfor
    draw gene;
    label.lrt(decimal length gene, llcorner currentpicture);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

If you want to go further you need to add `\mplibnumbersystem{double}` as shown in the example.  Then you can increase it a bit more.  This is what it looks like at the 8th level (which takes 3.1 sec to produce on my elderly macbook) with 131072 steps in the path.

[image]